# Marketing Cloud Connector problem

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

For some reason, my Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud got disconnected. 
I started the "usual" troubleshooting procedure - cleared out the tokens, but even after that I cannot reconnect them. 
When I go to MC tab in Sales Cloud, I am able to log in with my MC API user credentials, but if I try to click on ***Change Marketing Cloud User*** or ***Configure Marketing Cloud Connector*** I get the following message:

> Sorry, something went wrong. We couldn't retrieve the API User
>   details. Try again or open a support case in the Help and Training
>   portal.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support was not helpful at all, but I managed to resolve the issue by deleting the existing Configuration, as described here, and re-configuring MC Connect once again:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231095&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 0):

Since the user tokens are only visible to support and from what I heard from them aren't the same all the time, its better to raise a request and ask them to look into it.